# Отсутствует перевод по неудачным результатам поиска

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, поиск

Например, на [такой поисковый запрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%20user%3Ame) я вижу следующее:

> [image: поиск]

Comment: Обновилось. Только забыл одну фразу. https://ru.traducir.win/string/11890. Добавил предложение.

Comment: @Suvitruf еще Search options. И кое-что подправил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предложил:

1. https://ru.traducir.win/string/11895

   > Нам не удалось ничего найти по фразе **$displayTerms$**
2. https://ru.traducir.win/string/11909

   > Нам не удалось ничего найти по фразе **$displayTerms$**, исключая **$excludeTerms$**
3. https://ru.traducir.win/string/11905

   > Нам не удалось ничего найти по фразе **$displayTerms$**, исключая **$excludeTerms$** с метками $tags$
4. https://ru.traducir.win/string/11904

   > Нам не удалось ничего найти по фразе **$displayTerms$** с метками $tags$
5. https://ru.traducir.win/string/11893

   > Нам не удалось ничего найти
6. https://ru.traducir.win/string/11890

   > Попробуйте другие и менее конкретные ключевые слова.